# How to fix TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)?

Tags: python, typeerror, operands

This is my code to read .csv files. I want to devide the data to training set and testing set and label them.
       `

```
train_df = file_full[:len(file_full)//2]

labels=[ 0 for i in range(len(file_full))//2]

train_df=train_df.appen(file_bottom[:len(file_bottom)//2])

for i in range(len(file_bottom)//2):

    labels.append(1)

    train_df['label']=labels

    train = train_df.drop('label',axis=1)

    train_label= train_df['label']`
```

However, I am getting this error.

> labels=[ 0 for i in range(len(file_full))//2]
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'range' and 'int'

I thought is providing a number and I am taking half of it. what is the problem?

Comment: You probably want `range(len(file_full)//2)`, i.e. dividing the length not the range.

Comment: Side-note, you want to use `enumerate` instead of `range(len())`

Comment: easier as `labels=[0] * (len(file_full)//2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parenthesis are wrong. You are trying to divide a range object by two, which doesn't make sense. Try this:

```
labels=[ 0 for i in range(len(file_full)//2)]
```